# How to camera track a soft body object

Tags: camera

I am making a simulation and need the camera to actively follow a soft body as it moves, Ive used the Track to constraint but it only targets the origin but not the actual body as it moves. I also want to know if there is a way to have its location move with the body but not rotation. thank you.

Comment: You can use hooks to parent a vertex to an empty, then use that empty to control the camera.

Comment: How would you go about this when i try to hook the empty to the vertex group it ends up glitching out the mesh and the empty doesnt move with the soft body

Comment: "Glitching out the mesh" is a term that is hard to understand. Please modify the text of the original question and add what you have tried and the results you are getting.